# SAP Business Objects Webi: same report but the output changes based on the username

Tags: business-objects

SAP Business Objects Webi:

Assume there is a report ABC.wid. Am trying to achieve the following: When a user x logins, he should get data in line chart in ABC.wid. When a user y logins, he should get data in horizontal table in ABC.wid. So its the same report but the output changes based on the username. Is there a possibility of getting this done in SAP BO 4.2.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create both Chart and Table in the report, then in table/chart properties configure it to hide based on the CurrentUser() value

Answer (score 0):

I have not done this myself, but I think you should be able to do this using a "Publication". Check this out...

https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Personalization+in+SAP+Business+Intelligence+4.0+Web+Intelligence+Publications

Noel

Comment: Yes we can filter data being send to users in publication. But my question was regarding report refresh.